# PHP Function wp_kses incorrectly called

Tags: php

I cloned a working AWS EC2 Instance and moved some sites over from old server instances that were running Wordpress 6.2.2, PHP 7.3 and Windows Server 2008. The new instance is running Wordpress 6.2.2, php 8.0 and Windows Server 2016. Now the moved sites are giving me this error:

**PHP Notice: Function wp_kses_allowed_html was called incorrectly. When using the CUSTOM_TAGS constant, make sure to set these globals to an array: $allowedposttags, $allowedtags, $allowedentitynames, $allowedxmlentitynames.**

They were functioning perfectly on the 2008 server. Can someone tell me the source of this problem and how to correct this?

I have disabled the plugins, changed the default theme, tried changing php versions... If I switch to PHP 7.3.10 I get an "unrecognized authentication" error and it won't connect to the database.

Comment: The error above should read PHP Notice: not HP Notice.

Comment: The constant `CUSTOM_TAGS` defaults to `false`, however some bit of your site appears to be setting it. I'd grep for that

Comment: THANK YOU CHRIS!!! It was in my wp.config file. I defined it false, turned my plugins back on and boom! Up she came.